# Expandable sidebar (div) OVER the entire website (in background)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying for 2 days how to implement a sidebar on my project, like Feedly.com sidebar

All scripts/snippets/codes I tried, destructs my design and move all divs, etc. I think the best option is to create a div OVER all my site. How can I do this??

**What I have right now:**

[image: What I have right now]

**What I want to do:**

[image: What I want]

[image: What I want]

Thanks for your time;
Best regards,

Comment: What have you tried? Looks like a simple fixed-position'ed div eliminates the problem.

Comment: I just tried some simple code like http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/2/ 
or jQuery plugins like Sidr, but in both cases my template is broke :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a sidebar all you need is:

```
.sidebar {
     /* Dimensions */
    width: 3.8em; /* adjust it to make it wider or narrower */
    height: 100%; /* to be the entire height of the window */

    /* Positioning */
    position: fixed; /* to stay fixed on the screen */
    top: 0;
    left: 0; /* Or right: 0 to put right */

    /* Visibility */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, the trick was using 'position: fixed;'. Thanks dude! :)